# Node.js + JavaScript: return value, not [object HTMLDivElement]

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

First of all - I'm not a coder, I'm here posting for the first time. I tried different ways for a couple of days and cannot get this to work.

I have a problem displaying temperature which is received from serial port to the web page.

Here is my **app.js** code:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var SerialPort = require("serialport");
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(8080);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var serialport = new SerialPort("/dev/cu.wchusbserialfd1210", {
    baudrate: 9600,
    parser: SerialPort.parsers.readline("\r\n")
});
serialport.on('open', function(){
    // Now server is connected to Arduino
    console.log('Serial Port Opened');

    var lastValue;
    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        //Connecting to client 
        console.log('Socket connected');
        socket.emit('connected');
        var lastValue;

        serialport.on('data', function(data){
            console.log(`Serial got: ${data}`);
            var temperature1 = data.trim();
            if(lastValue !== temperature1){
                socket.emit('data', temperature1);
            }
            lastValue = temperature1;
        });
    });
});
```

Then in **index.html** I have created this function:

```
function getTemperatureA() {
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
    var temperature1 = 0;
    socket.on('data', function (data) {
        tt1 = data;
    });
    return tt1;
}
```

And when in index.html file I use this code:

```
document.getElementById('tt1').innerHTML = "Temperature: " + getTemperatureA();
```

I get this:

**Temperature: [object HTMLDivElement]**

If I use my function as this:

```
function getTemperatureA(id) {
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
    var temperature1 = 0;
    var box = document.getElementById(id);
    socket.on('data', function (data) {
        box.innerHTML = data;
    });
}
```

And then in index.html this:

```
<div id="tt1"></div>
getTemperatureA('tt1');
```

Then it is working and showing temperature as 24.2 (for example).

So the main question is how to return just a value? I need this value in another function to draw a gauge for the temperature using value from my function?

Comment: You can't return a value in a situation like that. The second version of your function is the way it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed this to work by removing getTemperatureA() function. The problem was that Gauge was loaded before data from serial port was received. So socket.on must be called after JustGage.

Here is my **index.html** file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Temperature</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'OpenSans';
        src: url('fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
    }

    body {
        font-family: 'OpenSans';
        background-color: black;
        text-align: center;
        color: grey;
    }

    #t1 {
        width:120px; height:100px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0.5px;
    }

    </style>
    <script src="/js/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/raphael-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/justgage.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="t1"></div>
    <script>
         document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
            var tt1;
            var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');

            var t1 = new JustGage({
                title: "",
                label: "Temperature",
                id: "t1",
                value: tt1,
                min: -50,
                decimals: true,
                decimals: 1,
                max: 50,
                symbol: '\xB0C',
                gaugeWidthScale: 0.5,
                customSectors: [{
                    color: "#0000ff",
                    lo: -50.0,
                    hi: -20.0
                }, {
                    color: "#33ceff",
                    lo: -19.9,
                    hi: -10.0
                }, {
                    color: "#33ffff",
                    lo: -9.9,
                    hi: 0
                }, {
                    color: "#33ffda",
                    lo: 0.1,
                    hi: 17.9
                }, {
                    color: "#00ff00",
                    lo: 18.0,
                    hi: 22.9
                }, {
                    color: "#ffff00",
                    lo: 23.0,
                    hi: 25.9
                }, {
                    color: "#ffa500",
                    lo: 26.0,
                    hi: 29.9
                }, {
                    color: "#ff0000",
                    lo: 30.0,
                    hi: 50.0
                }],
                counter: true,
                pointer: true,
                titleFontColor: "grey",
                titleFontFamily: "OpenSans",
                valueFontColor: "grey",
                valueFontFamily: "OpenSans",
                formatNumber: false
            });

            socket.on('data', function (data) {
                //tt1 = parseFloat(data);   
                t1.refresh(tt1);
            });
         });

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Anyway, thanks for the support!

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing responsibilities in `getTemperatureA()`. You'll want to separate these and use them appropriately. To break it down; first, there's the job of connecting to, and registering a data event handler for, a websocket. Then there's the job of doing something with the incoming data (storing it for further use). And finally there's the need to reference that data.

Connecting and registering an event handler only needs to be down once, so you can just create a function like:

```
var tt1;
function connectToHost() {
    // concern 1: connect and register callback
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
    socket.on('data', function (data) {
        // concern 2: save the data
        tt1 = data;
    });
}
```

and then call it at an appropriate time, such as at `document.ready`. Then, in the code in which you need the current temperature, you can reference `tt1` directly, or if for some reason it really does need to be a function that returns a value you can use a function such as:

```
function getTemperatureA() {
    return tt1;
}
```

Comment: When I use the function connectToHost() that you suggested and try to display using `<div id="TA"></div>` and `document.getElementById('TA').innerHTML = "Temperature: " + tt1;` then I get **undefined**.

Comment: Either you're doing that `innerHTML` assignment before the socket is connected and data has been received, or tt1 is not in scope with that call. Perhaps you could share some more of the client code (index.html)?